# Jekyll Variable '{{' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}

Tags: jekyll

In the post markdown I use a double brace `{{` which on `jekyll 2.5.3` returns an error:

```
Jekyll Variable '{{' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}
```

The content is replaced with:

```
<article class="post-content">
    {{ content }}
</article>
```

in the template

When I remove this line from the post markdown it works prefectly:

```
`{{` **Double Curly Braces** indicate that data will be replaced with data binding
```

Why is this happening?

**Update:**

Stack trace:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.6.1/lib/liquid/block.rb:78:in `create_variable': Variable '{{' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/  (Liquid::SyntaxError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.6.1/lib/liquid/block.rb:38:in `parse'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.6.1/lib/liquid/document.rb:5:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.6.1/lib/liquid/template.rb:59:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.6.1/lib/liquid/template.rb:59:in `parse'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/liquid-2.6.1/lib/liquid/template.rb:46:in `parse'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:106:in `render_liquid'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:233:in `do_layout'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/post.rb:261:in `render'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:298:in `block in render'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:297:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:297:in `render'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:51:in `process'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:56:in `build'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:34:in `process'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/bin/jekyll:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you provide command with --trace like `jekyll build --trace`.

Comment: @DavidJacquel Updated

Comment: You have a bad closing somewhere `}` single brace or `%}` tag clasing, instead of `}}`

Comment: Look in your pages, posts, collections, templates, includes,...

Comment: When I remove that line from the updated question, it works perfectly though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to wrap that line in `{% raw %} / {% endraw %}` tags to stop it being processed by the liquid template engine.

```
{% raw %}
`{{` **Double Curly Braces** indicate that data will be replaced with data binding
{% endraw %}
```